# How to fix 'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am facing with the problem of setting the app_name attribute in the included module. 
Despite the fact that I have seen similar answers on how to fix it, I did not find something working for me.

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from intranet import views,forms
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.urls import reverse

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'pharmakeia', views.PharmakeiaViewSet,base_name='pharmakeia')
router.register(r'doctors', views.DoctorsViewSet,base_name='doctors')
router.register(r'new-pharmakeia', views.VriskoViewSet,base_name='new-pharmakeia')
router.register(r'new-all-pharmakeia', views.VriskoAllViewSet,base_name='new-all-pharmakeia')
 views.json_data,base_name='test_pharmakeia')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest/', include(router.urls, namespace='rest')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include(rest_framework.urls, namespace='rest_framework')),
```

Then I changed the script:

**I tried to declare an app_name variable**

```
app_name="intranet"
```

**and then I tried to fix the urls containing the include function**

```
url(r'^rest/', include((router.urls,app_name), namespace='rest')),
url(r'^api-auth/', include(('rest_framework.urls',app_name), namespace='rest_framework')),
```

I face a new problem 
**"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router'** despite the fact that I have already defined rooter**

Here is my output from command line

```
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator/urls.py", line 40, in <module>
    url(r'^rest/', include(router.urls, namespace='rest')),
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 39, in include
    'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

^C(geolocator_venv) [root@76 geolocator]# clear

(geolocator_venv) [root@76 geolocator]# python manage.py runserver 76.neurosynthesis.com:19999
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator/urls.py", line 40, in <module>
    url(r'^rest/', include(router.urls, namespace='rest')),
  File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 39, in include
    'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try to add `app_name="intranet"` in your `rest_framework.urls` file

Comment: @PankajSharma I don't have any rest_framework.urls in my project

Comment: try `include((router.urls, 'rest'))` without the `namespace` argument, which should give the app name space "rest" to your urls.